# Galleria Fullscreen theme captions between image and thumbnails

Tags: jquery, slideshow, galleria

I'm using the [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/) jQuery slideshow framework.

My question is, how can I bottom-align the caption in the Fullscreen theme, so it's between the thumbnails and the main image, without cropping the images, with white (i.e. blank) space behind it?

In other words, is there a way to place the description so that it's not overlapping the main image?

I posted [this question](http://getsatisfaction.com/galleria/topics/fullscreen_theme_captions_between_image_and_thumbnails) on the Galleria support site a few months ago, but I can't get any help from the developer.

[Here's my page](http://bit.ly/kSx6dF).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image dimensions are being calculated somewhere in the code, dig it out and minus 20-50 pixels from the height.

Comment: I've tried going through the javascript but can't find a way to shorten the image height. I'd also be wary of editing core files; Galleria has an extend function for things like this. I'm just not sure what code to write.

Comment: After processing the stage and image height, add 20px to the stage height.

Comment: What exactly do I need to write to do that?